# What bonusses does a Roman Empire and a Roman Republic give?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

After some time in the Roman campaign a civil war breaks out. After dealing with the senate loyalist faction I get the option to chose between a Roman Republic or an Empire.

I chose the empire option which gave me a reduction in corruption and a reduction in upkeep costs. What would the choice for a republic have given me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Choosing the republic gives you two extra recruitment slots and a 10% discount on unit training across all provinces.

Answer (score 4):

.

```
Playing as Carthage, Empire gives: -10% unit upkeep and -25% corruption
---
And Republic gives:
2 recruitment slots and -10% discout on unit training across all provinces
```